# Feynman-Kac representation for Cauchy problem with boundary conditions.

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I have the following PDE:

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u=\mathcal A u, (t,x)\in [0,T]\times [a,b]\\
u(0,x)=g(x),\\
u(t,a)=f(t),
\end{cases}
\end{align}

where $\mathcal A$ is some second-order differential operator.

I would like to know if there's a Feynman-Kac representation for the solution of the latter (assuming of course that the operator satisfies all the necessary conditions). Honestly I don't know how to treat the boundary condition here.

If yes, could you please add some reference?

Thanks in advance.